# Библиотека генерации 3d документов для Блендера

Tags: .net, 3d, blender

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я разрабатываю приложение, которое должно визуализировать и возвращать в виде документа 3d представление различных блоков. С визуализацией проблему удалось решить. Теперь необходимо разработать сохранение.
То есть есть набор примитивов. Их надо расположить на нужных местах и нарисовать связи между ними (и возвратить в виде документа любого приемлемого для Блендера формата - 3ds, obj, dxf. Разве что только не stl, так как там всё обрисовывается треугольниками). 
Посоветуйте бесплатные 3d библиотеки, которые могли бы выполнить эти функции.

Comment: Вопрос широк и неясен. Приведите хотя бы иллюстрацию.

Comment: Сделано. Сложные фигуры - это примитивы, которые я планирую подгружать из БД (то есть рассчитываю на функции импорта), трубы можно отрисовать и просто цилиндрами.

Comment: Почему бы не написать питон-скрипт, который будет, выполняясь в самом blender, генерировать опять-же наитивный blend-файл?

Answer (score 0):

**Вот пример, как сгенерировать простую сцену.**

Данный метод генерирует бленд-файл со стандартным кубом.

Вызов блендера из командной строки:

```
blender -P test.py -b startscene.blend
```

`-P` - запуск python скрипта
`-b` - открытие файла без GUI

*test.py:*

```
import bpy

#создаем куб
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 1))

#сохраняем сцену   
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="/path/to/file/test.blend")
```

В результате сохраняется файл со стандартным кубом внутри. Соответственно `startscene.blend` может содержать объекты из которых просто дублированием и перемещением на нужные позиции вы сможете собрать сцену. Вам останется только сгенерировать py-файл из вашего приложения.

Comment: Эта вещь сформирована в Babylon.js и отображается в браузере. Мне же нужна логика отрисовки в файл, которая будет запускаться на сервере. А для этого нужна .net библиотека.

Comment: @Jakobinec Вы не можете установить blender на сервере?

Comment: Нет - не разрешат.

Comment: Что-ж тогда я не могу помочь. Но ответ оставлю, он может быть полезен для кого-то другого